# Where is Grails application getting deployed and how can I see the files?

Tags: eclipse, grails

Grails noob here. I am updated a .png file in my Eclipse grails project but it is not getting picked up. I do a `grails clean` restart grails but still no luck.

To start the Grails server I do:

> Run / Run Configurations / Grails command = run-app.

I am wondering where is this server and is there any way I can see what files it using?  I'd like to see this so I can see my clean really is a clean and so I can figure out why new versions of files are not getting picked up.

Note: I am using STS plugin

Comment: Your problem can be browser cache, have you tried clean it? I'm sure that there's already a question about tomcat location in SO.

Comment: By default Grails use Tomcat for deployment, and at last resort you can always customize Grails to use your own Tomcat container:
Refer: http://grails.org/plugin/tomcat